# Not all namespaces are included into Sandcastle build for documentation

Tags: c#, sandcastle

I have a C# project with two namespaces in one solution. I've documented all the classes/functions/members/etc in both namespaces. As this project is a small research project, the namespaces are `DocTestLibrary` and `DocTestLibrary.Events`. However, when I try to create documentation from it via Sandcastle, it will only create documentation for the `DocTestLibrary` namespace. Is there any setting that I need to make in Sandcastle to make this work? I doubt it though, as I've scoured through most of them.

The strange thing is, Doxygen is able to generate documentation just fine.

---

As to provide some more information, I've checked the log that Sandcastle produces for the build.
It seems that this entry is causing the rest not to be displayed.

```
Warn: ResolveReferenceLinksComponent2: Unknown reference link target 'T:DocTestLibrary.Events.DemoEvent'.
```

I also found out something else.

The `DocTestLibrary` namespace consists of two classes:

- TestClass
- StaticHelper

As the name implies, the StaticHelper is a helper-class with only static methods. Yet Sandcastle also denies to process this file. Only the TestClass get's processed. It only boggles me that there isn't an entry about this in the log though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this issue is fixed by setting the `DocumentInternals` in the `Visibility` properties section in the Sandcastle project. I wonder why this is, as no code is declared internal...

I guess I'll be playing around some more...

Answer (score 13):

In my sandcastle project it would always only include a single namespace of a total 5. The problem was that I did not check **Include root namespace container** under the section **Help File**. 
Now all my namespaces are listed unter a root namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Are all your types in `DocTestLibrary.Events` internal by any chance? By default, I believe Sandcastle only generates documentation for public types.

Comment: Everything is declared public except for two private strings. Nothing is declared internal.

Comment: @ThaMe90: You do understand that the *default* visibility for non-nested classes is internal, not public, right? So just `class Foo` is an internal class.

Comment: That was an aspect that I didn't know about default visibility for C#. I was taught that in Java the default was public. As there only was public, private and protected. I never even thought of the possibility of internal being the default.

Comment: @ThaMe90: In Java the default is "package" access (which can't be explicitly declared), not public... and Java and C# have very different rules. Basically in C#, the default is always "the most restricted you could declare it to be" - so fields are private by default, for example.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. Thanks for filling me in. :) What I know about C# is mostly self-taught, and well, you tend to miss important bits here and there.

Comment: @ThaMe90: I would thoroughly recommend that you get hold of the language specification (ideally in hard copy, but at least download it) and a good book about C# too. Still, at least it sounds like all the mysteries have been explained...

Answer (score 2):

I've found this issue can be fixed by manually setting the classes you want documented in Edit API Filter under Project Properties -> Visibility.