# Sandcastle not generating documentation for namespace children

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation, sandcastle

I've just setup Sandcastle (https://shfb.codeplex.com) to handle exporting all my code's XML documentation into a nice HTML file.

The issue I'm facing is that while Sandcastle is generating documentation for my top level namespace fine (eg: Countries), any classes within a child namespace (eg: Countries.Europe) aren't being documented.

All classes are set as public, and wwithin Sandcastle Help File Builder's visibility section, Private fields, internal members, protected members and protected members of sealed classes are enabled.

Is there some kind of limitation I'm unaware of that's preventing Sandcastle from documenting my child namespaces, or have I just set it up incorrectly?

Comment: This question is an oldie, but I am running into a similar problem. I have a namespace with two classes. One public. One internal. The documentation always says the internal class has a "Missing Summary". Did you find any resolution to this issue?

Comment: I found i solution at here. [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849679/not-all-namespaces-are-included-into-sandcastle-build-for-documentation)